# Creating json string using json lib

Tags: c++, c, json, string

I am using [jsonc-libjson](https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/json-c-libjson-tutorial/) to create a json string like below.

```
{ "author-details": {
        "name" : "Joys of Programming",
        "Number of Posts" : 10
    }
}
```

My code looks like below

```
json_object *jobj = json_object_new_object();
json_object *jStr1 = json_object_new_string("Joys of Programming");
json_object *jstr2 = json_object_new_int("10");
json_object_object_add(jobj,"name", jStr1 );
json_object_object_add(jobj,"Number of Posts", jstr2 );
```

this gives me json string

```
{
 "name" : "Joys of Programming",
    "Number of Posts" : 10
}
```

How do I add the top part associated with author details?

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase an old advertisement, "libjson users would rather fight than switch."

At least I assume you must like fighting with the library. Using [nlohmann's JSON library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json), you could use code like this:

```
nlohmann::json j {
    { "author-details", {
            { "name", "Joys of Programming" },
            { "Number of Posts", 10 }
        }
    } 
};
```

At least to me, this seems somewhat simpler and more readable.

Parsing is about equally straightforward. For example, let's assume we had a file named `somefile.json` that contained the JSON data shown above. To read and parse it, we could do something like this:

```
nlohmann::json j;

std::ifstream in("somefile.json");

in >> j;   // Read the file and parse it into a json object

// Let's start by retrieving and printing the name.
std::cout << j["author-details"]["name"];
```

Or, let's assume we found a post, so we want to increment the count of posts. This is one place that things get...less tasteful--we can't increment the value as directly as we'd like; we have to obtain the value, add one, then assign the result (like we would in lesser languages that lack `++`):

```
j["author-details"]["Number of Posts"] = j["author-details"]["Number of Posts"] + 1;
```

Then we want to write out the result. If we want it "dense" (e.g., we're going to transmit it over a network for some other machine to read it) we can just use `<<`:

```
somestream << j;
```

On the other hand, we might want to pretty-print it so a person can read it more easily. The library respects the width we set with `setw`, so to have it print out indented with 4-column tab stops, we can do:

```
somestream << std::setw(4) << j;
```

Comment: I second the motion to use nlohmann's library. I've used it before without too much trouble and with success.

Comment: Thanks all for recommending nlohmann's JSON. I will try that out. To jump start,  If someone can throw snippet of how to parse json data/object like above using the nlohman's json library that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new JSON object and add the one you already created as a child.

Just insert code like this after what you've already written:

```
json_object* root = json_object_new_object();
json_object_object_add(root, "author-details", jobj); // This is the same "jobj" as original code snippet.
```

Comment: It doesn't produce the desired results.  json_object *jobj = json_object_new_object();                                                         
json_object* root = json_object_new_object ();                                              
json_object_object_add(jobj, "author-details", root);   I added this before the code I provided earlier.  json_object *jobj = json_object_new_object();
json_object *jStr1 = json_object_new_string("Joys of Programming");
json_object *jstr2 = json_object_new_int(10); 
It prints  { "author-details": { }, "name": "Joys of Programming", "Number of Posts": 10 }

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from Dominic, I was able to figure out the correct answer.

```
json_object *jobj = json_object_new_object();
json_object* root = json_object_new_object();
json_object_object_add(jobj, "author-details", root);
json_object *jStr1 = json_object_new_string("Joys of Programming");
json_object *jstr2 = json_object_new_int(10);
json_object_object_add(root,"name", jStr1 );
json_object_object_add(root,"Number of Posts", jstr2 );
```